# TypeScript, SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to run my program using "node main.js", however, it keeps coming up with the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

```
D:\Visual Studio Code Projects\ts-hello>node main.js
D:\Visual Studio Code Projects\ts-hello\main.js:1
import { LikeComponent } from './like.component';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

I have tried changing the tsconfig.json file to "module": "commonjs", however, this did not work. I have even uninstalled and reinstalled node and started from scratch.

```
import{LikeComponent} from './like.component';

let component = new LikeComponent(10, true);
component.onClick();
console.log(`likesCount: ${component.likesCount}, isSelected: ${component.isSelected}`);
```

It should output the program correctly onto the command prompt.

Comment: Use the compiler option `"module": "commonjs"` in `tsconfig.json`. Then compile again.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by the compiler option?
I have already gone into the config file and changed module to "module": "commonjs",

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that your are running `node main.js`.

Your `main.js` currently has `esm` syntax (aka ES6 module syntax).

Assuming it is compiled from `main.ts`, you need to have `module: commonjs` in your `tsconfig.json

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    ... // other configurations
  }
}
```

With that, when you compile your code by running `tsc`, it will create `main.js` with commonjs module syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to debug a vscode project and you already have `"module": "commonjs",` then check your "launch.json" `outFiles` to make sure it aligns with where your output files actually are (typically set via `outDir`):

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.ts",
      "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/build/**/*.js"], //make sure this matches!
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

It seems like if vscode doesn't find a matching file, it just attempts to run the ts file via node (which explains the error).

I just thrashed on this for a while, so hopefully this saves someone else some headache.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of errors crop up because of syntax differences between versions of Javascript/ECMAScript. They can be avoided by using the configurations found in the [@tsconfig/bases github repository](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases) which are [recommended by the TypeScript team](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#tsconfig-bases). Just make sure to use the corresponding tsconfig for the environment the Javascript is intended to run in.

The TSConfig Bases are available for install on NPM. Install and then extend the @tsconfig/node12/tsconfig.json like so:

`npm install --save-dev @tsconfig/node12`

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node12/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue stemmed from problems installing all of the required packages from npm. I deleted my `node_modules` folder and used `yarn` to install again, and then `yarn install --check-files` to ensure they were installed correctly.